# How do I stop a download?

Tags: file-transfer, downloading

I accidentally clicked on a download link and started a download. Once the download started, I didn't know how to cancel it. Later, it occurred to me that I could have ended the connection.

Either way, how do you stop a download once started?

I have a HTC Wildfire S, a v2.3.5 Android if that matters.

Comment: From which app are you downloading?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Download notification showing the progress and it will take you to Downloads app. There in app you can cancel the download.

Comment: Clicking on the download notification showing the progress doesn't do anything. I have a HTC Wildfire S, a v2.3.5 Android if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus Zenfone 2 still running Lollipop, and I've had the same problem for a long time. Force-stopping the Download Manager app and clearing the data usually works, but I recently stumbled upon a new way to cancel the download, making sure that it is permanently cancelled and doesn't pop up again annoyingly.

It merely involves going to the Storage section under Settings, and clicking on the Downloads tab. This brings up a list of previous and ongoing downloads. From here, long-pressing on a download lets you cancel it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome, then the download notification should appear on the screen. In case it doesn't, go to Setting > Apps > Google Chrome and force stop the app.