# How to stop speech recognition download?

Tags: downloading

http://postimg.org/image/qyxwjj2f1/

Here is a picture of the screen. 
It says Downloading English (US) Offline speech recognition data 108%.

When the download started itself I lost the internet connection so it never succesfully downloaded. Now even after I restart I still get "Downloading..." in the status bar but nothing happens (even when connected to the internet).

I just want to clear the status bar of this stuck download.

Comment: Have you seen [How do I stop a download?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50329/16575) / [How do I force stop an application downloading from Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14783/16575)

Comment: Yes. It doesn't appear in the download list. Also, I don't know what app to stop. I tried google search but it's still there.

Comment: Usually you don't stop "an app", but "a download", as far as I understood. As I never had that issue, I better leave a good answer to someone who really can give it – unfortunately, I was only able to provide you with some links. You might wish to check [other questions tagged `downloading`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/downloading), with some luck you find a better hit.

Answer (score 2):

Tap and hold , then a window will appear, "App info". tap on it, it will bring you to the app manager, then tap on "Force stop"

Answer (score 2):

Settings > Language & Keyboard  > Voice search > Offline Speech recognition > All.

Cancel the download and restart the download if required.